# CalendarView and DeltaToken in different time range with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

From the Graph Documentation:
if you want a calendarView for a specific time range you use the query

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2017-01-01T19:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2017-01-07T19:00:00.0000000
```

if you want a delta token to get the changes in a calendarView you use the query

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime={start_datetime}&enddatetime={end_datetime}
```

My problem is taht I need to get all the events from a specific date at the beginning of my program, but after that I'm interesting to track changes of events from another date. 
 
So I'm wondering if is it possible to get a calendarView for a specific time range and a delta token for another time range **in a single query**?

Comment: While this does not seem to be possible based on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview, I am very much interested in being proven wrong. I would be interested in sliding time-window scopes: on every query tracking changes, I'd like to get the changes for the next 24 hours counting from that time. In fact, I expect this is a common use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in a single query. Please issue two separate queries.

Thanks!
Sri

Comment: Thank you. Yes in fact ( as workaround ) I make two different request, the first with a specific time range to get the events that I was interested for (discarding the delta token), and the second with another time range to get the delta token (discarding the events that I received) and track the changes